# Split undirected weighted graph into k equal subgraphs while minimizing weight of cutted edges

Tags: python, algorithm

I have the following weighted graph with 28 vertices:
[image]

My goal is to split this Graph into k (in this case 3) partitions that are nearly of the same size (10, 9, 9) so that the edge weights in the partitions are maximized (the cut edge weights are minimized).

I have read a lot about k-cut algorithms but couldn't find one that returns partitions which sizes are as equal as possible.

Despite of that I found this: https://towardsdatascience.com/a-simple-and-fast-deterministic-algorithm-for-the-minimum-k-way-cut-74d7ee2a521a

It is now running for about 2 hours on an Amazon EC2 z1d.6xlarge with 192GiB of RAM utilizing 140 GiB of it in the moment. So I think I will get out of RAM on it soon.

It isn't neccessary to find the absolute minimum cut. So an deterministic algorithm is not a must.

Any advice is appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

With only 28 vertices, you can probably just smart-force it, like brute force, but a little smarter. Benefit here is that these kinds of things tend to be a fair bit easier to implement.

Randomly split your nodes in 3 groups of the desired size. Now we just figure out how many elements we are moving around. Basically figure out how many values will be taken from each group. Then generate the possible combinations of those being taken out. Then combine the values and generate the permutations for those values and distribute each to the group they are swapped out of and then calculate the new sum after the swap.

Example where the combination is 5

```
# This is more psuedo code than valid code, though it's based on Ruby
nodes = node.shuffle # Randomize the order of the nodes list
A = nodes.pop(9)
B = nodes.pop(9)
C = nodes # Remaining 10

min_k = 1 # Adjust if you want to say resume calculations
K = 9
best_weight = 0
best_combo = nil
(min_k..K).each do |a|
  (1..(K - i)).each do |b|
    c = K - a - b # a + b + c = k, a,b,c <= K
    a_combinations = A.combinations(a) # https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/combination
    b_combinations = B.combinations(b)
    c_combinations = C.combinations(c)
    products = a_combinations.product(b_combinations,c_combinations)
    # https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/product
    products.each do |a_values, b_values, c_values|
      values = a_values + b_values + c_values # Merge values into 1 list
      permutations = values.permutations(values.size) # All possible orderings
      permutations.each do |permutation| # https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/permutation
        new_a_values = permutation.pop(a)
        new_b_values = permutation.pop(b)
        new_c_values = permutation.pop(c) # permutation should now be an empty list
        # Swap out old values with new values
        new_A = A.duplicate().delete_all(a_values).add_all(new_a_values)
        new_B = B.duplicate().delete_all(b_values).add_all(new_b_values)
        new_C = C.duplicate().delete_all(c_values).add_all(new_c_values)
        # See how it worked out.
        new_weight = edge_weight(new_A) + edge_weight(new_B) + edge_weight(new_C)
        if new_weight >= best_weight
          best_weight = best_combo
          best_combo = [new_A,new_B,new_C]
          # definitely important to see results as the algorithm runs
          log("New Best Weight: " + best_weight + " by " + best_combo)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end 

return best_weight
```

I suspect you would get good results quickly with K=3 to K=5 (plus you can always generate a new random seed and run it again).

It's tricky to calculate the exact performance of this algorithm in terms of average case. But roughly speaking it should be about `O(K^2*K^(K/2)*k!)` Which is roughly `9^2*9^5*9!=` 10^12 loops (probably not practical). However, you should see fairly good results even at K=5, which only requires 375K loops on the high side. I imagine that is something that can be ran in a few minutes or less.